# Importing prefix golang?

Tags: go

From what I understand, golang imports modules like

```
import (
  "bitbucket.org/user/project"
  "github.com/user/project"
)
```

is there a way to import modules in all files, without explicitly typing an absolute remote location out, from

1) a single remote location?

2) multiple locations?

So for 1), you could specify somewhere that the host is github.com/user and any import that is not a default library and doesn't have a remote prefix is prefixed by github.com/user.  Or have a prefix_variable + relative/path and be able to set the prefix_variable somewhere?

So like

```
// in some config file
github = "github.com/user/"
bitbucket = "bitbucket.org/user/"

// imported in file
import ( 
  bitbucket + "project" // "bitbucket.org/user/project"
  github + "project" // "github.com/user/project"
)
```

or

```
// in some config file 
default = "github.com/user"

// imported in file
import (
  "bitbucket.org/user/project"  // this has a remote prefix, so default prefix is not added
  "project" // "github.com/user/project"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately to my knowledge there is no way to do this in the way you have stated. There is a discussion in Google Go Group which is somewhat related [Go Packaging: building a great packaging story](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/sfshThQ_wrA/6QVvQ5GlctEJ) which might give you some ideas of the thought process for why this cant be done (assuming you were not aware of this already).

I actually have a related problem which is associated with producing a build for two different server environments, one for Google App Engine and one for a local linux development environment sharing packages (imports) and I am still looking for the solution, hence watching this type of discussion.

Comment: For your problem, I think there is a specific 'precompilation' command for app engine vs non-app engine described here: http://blog.golang.org/the-app-engine-sdk-and-workspaces-gopath

Comment: Thanks. An answer before I even posted the question. Looks like exactly what I have been looking for and not stumbled accross.